# Timeline JS: How to set timeline start date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

I have been using TimelineJS from [here](http://timeline.verite.co/) with the JSON version of data retreival. It works fine but I cannot adjust the date that the time line starts at.

In the documentation it says to set up the JSON file as such:

```
    {
        "timeline":
        {
            "headline":"The Main Timeline Headline Goes here",
            "type":"default",
            "startDate":"1888",
            "text":"<p>Intro body text goes here, some HTML is ok</p>",
```

I have replicated this but just changed the details, eg:

```
{
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"HOT LATIN EVENTS",
        "type":"default",
        "startDate":"2012,09,30",
        "text":"Scroll through a list of Latin Music events>>> ",
        "date": [

             {
                "startDate":"2012,08,24",
                "headline":"PELIGRO Y SU BANDA  - Melbourne",
                "text":"<p><strong>Copacaban International</strong>, 139 Smith Street, Fitzroy, 3065</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://www.clavecontraclave.com/Peligro%20-%20Melbourne%20klein.jpg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            },
```

I have tried using just a year in `startDate` as well (eg: 2011) to no effect. The time line just starts at the first event below.

Anyone know whats going on?

Thanks

Comment: I'm also having issues with Timeline.js. I can't get the thing to even work.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found a way to directly specify a start date for timelines but you can iterate through your timeline slides to find the closest match, then use the index of that slide as your start_at_slide value. For example:

```
var timeline_dates = data_source.timeline.date;
var start_index = 0;
var target_date = new Date(); //set whatever date you want as your start date
for(x in timeline_dates) {
    var slide_date = new Date( timeline_dates[x].startDate );
    if( slide_date < target_date) start_index++;
}
```

Then when you instantiate your timeline, you'd use it like this:

```
createStoryJS({
    type:       'timeline',
    width:      '800',
    height:     '400',
    source:     data_source,
    embed_id:   'timeline_container',
    start_at_slide: start_index
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI, here's a direct link to the configuration options for TimelineJS (specifically, the "start at slide" attribute): https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS#start-at-slide